# Styling visited links via bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, firefox, hyperlink, bookmarklet

For a while a bookmarklet I made extensive use of has been broken for me in Firefox. It may apply to other browsers, but I only use it in Firefox.

The bookmarklet in question is "hide visited" from [squarefree](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagelinks.html).

Since this wasn't working (properly) I decided to have at it myself and ended up with this:

```
javascript:(
function(){
var css=document.createElement('style');
css.type='text/css';
var styles='a%3Avisited{display%3Anone !important}';
css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
})();
```

Broken up into several lines for readability, otherwise unmodified from what I'm using.
The thing is, it does append the inline stylesheet to the head, it just never alters the look of the links. Once I remove the `:visited` (or `%3Avisited` as it appears here), however, the stylesheet IS applied to links and they are hidden, though obviously the hiding is done regardless of their visited-state at this point.

Bottom line here is that I believe there is a problem with `:visited`, and flipping the bool for `layout.css.visited_links_enabled` in about:config, predictably, does nothing as this simply removes styling from visited links wholesale. This is undesirable. :)

It is probably worth noting that the squarefree bookmarklet still appends its stuff to the head, it simply has no effect either.

I am at a loss. What have I missed, and is it at all possible to hide visited links via a bookmarklet anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The behavior of `:visited` was changed a couple of years ago due to security reasons** ... while your code (and the squarefree bookmarklet) might work on older browsers, you won't be able to get the same impact in latest versions of the browsers

A note from https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

- **Visited links can only be different in color: foreground, background, outline, border, SVG stroke and fill colors**. All other style changes either leak the visitedness of the link by loading a resource or changing position or size of the styled content in the document, which can be detected and used to identify visited links.

Other useful references:

- http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/socialhistoryjs/ - what was the security problem (and its creative use)
- http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy - approach for the fix

For CSS, you can try for something like:

```
a:visited {
    color: white !important; /* It would hide the text if the background is white too */
    /* or some better css approach for your requirement */
}
```

Comment: I had read the first link you provided, and it never occurred to me that it would only disallow a certain set of instructions. While your color-option for the links works (despite being a `:visited` rule...) it doesn't quite cut it for my purposes.

That said, it's interesting to see that it actually does work, and it makes me wonder if perhaps there is room for more tinkering. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that you cannot find out which links have been visited with javascript anymore. This was done to protect user privacy. For security purposes, I believe that even attempting to style, or create styles for, visited links will not work in any current major browser.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons browsers have taken steps to prevent the "visited" status of links from being read by JavaScript. This means that any style you apply to ":visited" via CSS will not be registered in the DOM.

You can change things like color and text-decoration (probably), and the user will see the change on screen, but the result will not be readable to JS.

Why won't it apply "display:none"? Because if the browser were to remove the link from the page, this could alter the layout of the page, such as the height of a div, and provide a potential side channel for determining which links have been visited or not. For that reason "display:none" will not be applied.

The best solution I can suggest for your goal is to change the link color to match the background color, or perhaps modify the opacity.